# MonoTouch debug not building with ServiceStack.Text (AOT error)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, servicestack, aot

I have just started using the ServiceStack.Text.MonoTouch.dll in my MonoTouch solution. Everything compiles and runs in the simulator, but as soon as I try to run a Debug build on the phone the compilation process dies with the following error:
**error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '.../ServiceStack.Text.MonoTouch.dll'**

I have read this is due to the ServiceStack.Text dll being too large or something along those lines. So I tried in release mode and things work due to LLVM being on and the linker being turned to 'Link SDK assemblies only'.

This is problematic as I now am unable to debug on the device. In debug mode the linker is disabled, and LLVM is turned off. Is there any way around this?

MT 6.0.8 &
latest version of ServiceStack dll's off Github.

Answer (score 1):

> In debug mode the linker is disabled,

No (at least not by default).

By default the managed linker is enabled (Link SDK) for all device builds (debug or release). However the default (Link SDK) won't be able to remove unused code from `ServiceStack.Text.dll` since that assembly is not an **SDK** assembly.

You'll need to switch the option to **Link all assemblies** to ensure it gets processed.

Note that you might need to add `[Preserve]` attributes (or `--linkskip=ASSEMBLY`) on your own code if it's not linker safe (e.g. use of reflection). See this [thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/810/servicestack-text-not-working-with-link-all-assemblies-linker-behavior) for an example.

Comment: Tried changing the linker mode to 'Link all assemblies' in Debug and the AOT error still occurs.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the AOT error (it could be different from others we'have seen in similar cases). The **full** build log could be helpful too (but likely too big to include in your question).

Comment: Added the error that I get. Not sure if MT3001 means anything? Just strange how it does this in Debug mode.

Comment: Time for a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com including the full build log. The fact it *might* just happens in debug is that debug builds are much larger (than release) and the *suspected* bug is related to the object file size.

Comment: Logged. Lets see what Xamarin has to say.

Comment: What is the bug number? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue as Dylan (MT3001)